# xbox controller bluetooth connection ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, configuration

uname -a
Linux username 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I read all the tutorials and forums.

add "/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm=1" to /etc/sysfs.conf file

I initially it pairs (shows as connected) but the controller keeps blinking and then disconnect ...

I just bought the xbox controller (X/S 2020 forth generation model)
There is a lot of info out there (mainly for older version, distributions and models)...

Tried with terminal (using bluez, looking for error meaningful msgs):

```
bt-device -l

Added devices:
Xbox Wireless Controller (44:16:22:D1:F1:57)
bt-device -c 44:16:22:D1:F1:57
Connecting to: 44:16:22:D1:F1:57
Error: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout

dmesg | grep Bluetooth
```

(I get repetitions of these lines)

```
hci0: advertising data len corrected 20 -> 0
hci0: link tx timeout
hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x0a from 44:16:22:d1:f1:57
```

If it make sense to you, do you have any idea where I should be looking? thanks for your help...

Comment: https://community.stadia.com/t5/Stadia-General/Xbox-One-Controller-on-Ubuntu/m-p/12130


'sudo modprobe xpad'

helped but controller buttons are all mixed up

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I remove the device in bluethooth list, and setup..